# Does service hosted inside azure web app get static ips

Tags: azure, networking, ip, azure-appservice

I have deployed service inside azure web app >> then I login to the App Service inside Azure Portal and I can see a list on outbound ips, as follow:-

[image]

so are those static IPs? or they change overtime? we need the IP addresses as we are defining an white list of the services that can use our SMTP service. so can we rely on the above ips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> so are those static IPs? or they change overtime?

They are kind of static as they only change when performing [certain actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change), namely

- delete an app and recreate it in a different resource group
- delete the last app in a resource group and region combination and recreate it
- scale your app between the lower tiers (Basic, Standard, and Premium) and the Premium V2 tier

> so can we reply on the above ips?

Yes, your App Service will pick one of the IP addresses in the "Outbound IP addresses" field for outbound calls. If you use a Premium v2 plan the app will pick one of the addresses present in the "Additional Outbound IP Addresses" field.